# NCO netcdf command .exe Windows

Tags: windows, command, netcdf, nco

I have multiple netcdf files, and I want to join them with NCO. I know that it should be done with `ncrcat` in NCO , however when I want to use this command, it returns that the command couldn't be found! (Although it can find `ncecat`)
So I tried to install `ncrcat` with a command using

```
ln -s -f ncrcat.exe"
```

that I found in multiple forums. This is not working as well.
(Also I am using Windows)
Has anyone experience with his ?

Answer (score 2):

There is a packaging issue with NCO on Windows that we will fix in NCO 4.7.9 that causes ncrcat.exe and ncea.exe not to be installed. For now the best workaround is to copy ncra.exe to each of these executables, i.e.,

```
copy ncra.exe ncrcat.exe
copy ncra.exe ncea.exe
```

BTW Windows does not support symbolic links, so your command above will not work (also, it is malformed). Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!